# Completely deleting a database in sharded mongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb

I am planning to test a MongoDB cluster with some random data to test for performance. Then, I am planning to delete the data and use it for production.

My concern is that doing just the db.dropDatase() may not reclaim all the disk space in all the shards and config servers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25022517/4793847) from stack overflow says that "MongoDB does not recover disk space when actually data size drops due to data deletion along with other causes."

[This documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space) kind of says that "You do not need to reclaim disk space for MongoDB to reuse freed space. See Empty records for information on reuse of freed space" but I want to know the proper steps to delete a sharded MongoDB database.

I am currently on MongoDB 3.6.2.

Note: To people who may say I need a different Mongodb database for testing and production I want to make it clear that the production is itself a test to replace another old database. So right now, I am not looking for another big cluster just to test for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have here the best solution, i can explaint you but i would be wasting my time and you would be losing your time

[https://dzone.com/articles/reclaiming-disk-space-from-mongodb][1]